# Need to know variable name of Inner class that was defined in Outer class

Tags: swift

I have these two classes:

```
class User:Obj
{
    var firstBook:Book?
    var secondBook:Book?
}

class Book:Obj
{
   func getMyName() -> String
   {
      // Something need to do here
      // return name
   }
}

let user = User()

let book_1 = Book()
user.firstBook = book_1

let book_2 = Book()
user.secondBook = book_2

print(book_2.getMyName()) //Expected: secondBook
print(book_1.getMyName()) //Expected: firstBook
```

As you understand, I need to get the variable name of parent class.
Will be great if will be possible also to get parent class.Type

Comment: Why do you need to do this exactly?

Comment: Let's say firstBook and secondBook are separate tables in local DB and I need to get them from Book object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve something similar using reflection. You need to know about the user object inside the book object, so I've added a parent variable. It needs to be weak, to avoid retain cycles.

```
class User: Obj {

    var firstBook: Book? {
        didSet {
            firstBook?.parent = self
        }
    }

    var secondBook: Book?  {
        didSet {
            secondBook?.parent = self
        }
    }

}

class Book: Obj {

    weak var parent: Obj!

    func getMyName() -> String {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: parent)
        let variableName = mirror.children.filter { $0.value as? Book === self }.first?.label
        return variableName!
    }

}
```

Comment: It could be a solution, but I can't pass self when defining variables like this:
var firstBook = Book(self)

Comment: instead I can do this: var firstBook = Book(User.self),
if you can achieve the same results with this it will be great.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more clear how you would use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create property in Book class as name and set the name property to firstBook and secondBook and get it by retrieving name property

Comment: Not this way. Without setting properties.